# adding links with javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have h1 tag, which id called "step1". I would like to add link for that with Javascript. So i trying to code with javascript as follow:

```
    div = document.getElementById('step1');
 newlink = document.createElement('a');
  newlink.setAttribute('class', 'heading');
 newlink.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:showStep(2);');
 div.appendChild(newlink);
```

But it render only this way. `<h2 id="step1">Step<a href="javascript:showStep(1);" class="heading">` in HTML.

Actually I want following result as :

```
    <h2 id="step1"><a href="javascript:showStep(2);" 
class="heading">Choose Desired Services</a></h2>
```

So please help me to create this.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but your code works fine in my firefox 3.17, even with my IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just adding an element to trigger some JavaScript behavior, there's absolutely no need for it to be an `<a>` tag.  Just make a `<span>` and set its "onclick" attribute to the function you want to call:

```
var div = document.getElementById('step1');
var newlink = document.createElement('span');
newlink.onclick = function() { showStep(2); };
newlink.innerHTML = "Choose Desired Services";
div.appendChild(newlink);
```

You can also give it a class name etc. so that it can be styled appropriately (pointer cursor, whatever).

Also, **don't forget `var`!!**

Comment: but it created as follow. `<h2 id="step1">Choose Desired Services<span>Choose Desired Services</span></h2>`. I want this only. `<h2 id="step1"><span>Choose Desired Services</span></h2>`

Comment: i got it :) I added following code:  `newlink.innerHTML = "Choose Desired Services";
div.innerHTML = " ";
div.appendChild(newlink);`

Comment: Ah I see - yes, that will do it. I didn't realize that the text was already there in your `<h1>`.